# What is the proper term for printed book sides?

Tags: print-design, terminology

In german we call it »Schnittverzierungen«. There are different kinds of them, the most common one is »Farbschnitt«, where all sides are colored.

Here are some examples:

[image]

[Source](http://www.brandbook.de/blog/2013/10/der-b3-biennale-reader-das-buch-zur-ausstellung/)

[image: »Goldschnitt« with ornaments]

[Source](http://bubi-mayer.de)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could speak of *edge painting* or [*fore-edge painting*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fore-edge_painting), or *gilt-edged* for the golden variant.

Comment: The gilt edges here are also *goffered*. (Likely from *gaufré*; loosely "waffled", though the waffle is named for the pattern, not the other way around.)